# Как разместить слайдер на веб-странице?

Tags: веб-программирование, html

Доброго вам времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разместить "слайдер" в Html-документе?

```
<div class="sb-slider" id="index5">
    <img src="site.gif" title="Большое количество веб-сайтов и тонны информации"/>
    <img src="inter.jpg" title="Удобный и многофункциональный интерфейс"/>
    <img src="gazeta.jpg" title="Всегда свежие новости"/>
    <img src="dengi.jpg" title="Возможность развивать свой бизнес и получать хороший доход"/>
    <img src="site.jpg" title="Бесплатный хостинг"/>
    <img src="igra.jpg" title="Масса развлечений"/>
    <img src="mobile.jpg" title="Возможность воспользоваться сервисом даже через мобильное устройство"/>
</div>
```

-

```
$('#sb-slider').slicebox();
```

-

```
orientation         : 'v',
// ориентация (v)вертикально или (h)горизонтально.

perspective         : 1200,
// значение свойства -webkit-perspective.

slicesCount         : 1,
// число слоев нарезки, нужно нечетное число между 1 и 15
// (если вам нужно увеличить верхний предел, используйте функцию _validate).

disperseFactor      : 0,
// Каждый слой будет смещаться на x px по горизонтали / вертикали (в зависимости от ориентации).
// Средний слой не двигается.

 colorHiddenSides    : '#222',
// Цвет скрытых сторон.

sequentialRotation  : false,
// Анимация запускается слева-направо.
// Самый левый слой будет вращаться первым.

sequentialFactor    : 0,
// Если опция sequentialRotation имеет значение true, то здесь определяется задержка
// между началом вращения слоев в миллисекундах.

speed3d             : 800,
// Скорость анимации 3D.

speed               : 600,
// Скорость анимации при отсутствии 3D трансформаций.

fallbackEasing      : 'easeOutExpo',
// Эффект перехода при отсутствии 3D трансформаций.

slideshow           : false,
// Автопроигрывание слайдшоу.

slideshowTime       : 2000
// Интервал показа слайдов в сладшоу.<br>
```

Comment: Какой именно слайдер? Как по мне, то если у вас такие "навыки", то лучше это в чате обсудить. Тут есть чат? Хэшкод называется...

Comment: Нет.Просто я разместил, а у меня слайдер не открывается!

Comment: Скажите, в чём здесь ошибка?

Comment: Откуда я знаю, во 1-х ссылку бы на слайдер, во 2-х если у вас какой-либо скрипт упоратый, то ошибки смотрите в логах, в мозилле напр. в консоле firebug'a.

Comment: Скажите нахрена вы опции сюда вписали, вы их так же само и в скрипт у себя на сайте вставили? , по моему должен быть только блок с этими картинками и $('#sb-slider').slicebox(); , все остальное лишнее (пока-что), попробуйте так и посмотрите что в консоле за ошибки (если есть).

Comment: + К этому всему еще сам плагин должен быть подключен, вместе с jQuery и стилями. Я же говорил что чат нужен...

Answer (score 1):

судя по аналогичным скриптам слайдера, опции, которые вы написали ниже должны быть переданы функции в виде объекта, а не просто перечислены снизу. Сам код должен быть в тэгах <scritp></script> и должен или вызываться на событие загрузки документа или, что проще в вашем случае, должен быть помещен непосредственно перед закрывающим тэгом `</body>`

пр.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#sb-slider').slicebox({orientation : 'v', perspective : 1200});
</script>
```

так же, судя по всему, слайдер использует библиотеку вероятней всего jQuery, так что побеспокойтесь о том чтобы она была подключена к странице, и в скрипте слайдер запускается в элементе с атрибутом `id="sb-slider"`, которого в вашем примере я не вижу (у вас у элемента `class="sb-slider"`)